# Problem logging into default desktop environment

Tags: login, 15.04, lightdm

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04.

I cannot log graphically using the default desktop environment. 
When I try to log into the system it does nothing, and the login screen just stays as it. I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and re-init lightdm (`/etc/init.d/lightdm restart`). It asks me to login again.

When I open the `.xsession-errors` file it says:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: jayatana main process (21264) terminated with status 127
upstart: unity-gtk-module main process (21274) terminated with status 127
upstart: dbus pre-start process (21275) terminated with status 127
```

Using a different environment (I only have XBMC right now as alternative) works fine.

I tried creating a new user, or using the guest user, same thing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the `unity-gtk-module.log` I noticed that there was a problem with `initctl`.

Due to following a "recover" manual I had renamed it, and it couldn't be found.

I restored the original name and now it is working again :)